# spark structured streaming can not recive kafka message

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am testing spark structured streaming use kafka.i have a **kafka-broker(0.10.1)** on `host28`,default partition num:`num.partitions=1`

my producer：

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list host28:6667 --topic test
```

when i use

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper host26:2181,host27:2181,host28:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
```

or

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server host8:6667 --topic test --from-beginning --partition 0
```

can recive message from kafka.

But when use

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server host28:6667 --topic test --from-beginning
```

or spark structured streaming can't recive message

```
public class Main {
    private static String APP_NAE = "test_streaming_from_kafka";
    private static String KAFKA_HOST = "host28:6667";
    private static String KAFKA_SUBSCRIBE = "test";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName(APP_NAE)
                .getOrCreate();

        DataStreamReader reader = spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_HOST)
                .option("subscribe", KAFKA_SUBSCRIBE);

        StreamingQuery query = reader.load()
                .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)", "topic", "CAST(partition AS STRING)", "CAST(offset AS STRING)")
                .writeStream()
                .format("console")
                .start();

        query.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED！**

I changed spark log from `INFO` to `DEBUG`,then i found this：

> 18/08/17 21:12:07 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator: Received group
>   coordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1534511527794,
>   disconnected=false, request=ClientRequest(expectResponse=true,
>   callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@3d2afb1b,
>   request=RequestSend(header={api_key=10,api_version=0,correlation_id=117,client_id=consumer-1},
>   body={group_id=spark-kafka-source-f7b2afd9-e1c6-4d16-b299-6d629599cdc8-42875004-driver-0}),
>   createdTimeMs=1534511527794, sendTimeMs=1534511527794),
>   responseBody={error_code=15,coordinator={node_id=-1,host=,port=-1}})
>   18/08/17 21:12:07 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator: Group coordinator lookup
>   for group
>   spark-kafka-source-f7b2afd9-e1c6-4d16-b299-6d629599cdc8-42875004-driver-0
>   **failed: The group coordinator is not available**.

google `The group coordinator is not available` found [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/175137/error-the-group-coordinator-is-not-available-when.html)

Comment: Could someone paste the resolution for `The group coordinator is not available`. Not able to access link given above