# Spark Structure Streaming not able to read message from Kafka topics

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am using below code to read messages from kafka topics. But when in my cluster it's not able to read messages from kafka topics. But same is working in local machine with local kafka setup.

My cluster spark version is :
`20/10/29 13:15:20 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.0-cdh6.2.0`

My Cluster Kafka Version is:
`20/10/29 13:15:29 INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 2.1.0-cdh6.2.0`

My spark streaming kafka code is :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object KafkaTest {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

   val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .getOrCreate()
  
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('DEBUG')
  
  val df = spark.read
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "data1.company.com:9092")
        .option("subscribe", "onepartitiontopic")
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") // From starting
        .option("endingOffsets", "latest") // From starting
        .load()

df.printSchema()
df.show()
}
}
```

Below is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafkatest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

        
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>kafkatest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Below is console output of this program in cluster:

```
20/10/29 16:52:36 INFO state.StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)

20/10/29 16:52:38 INFO consumer.ConsumerConfig: ConsumerConfig values:
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.offset.reset = earliest
        bootstrap.servers = [data1.company.com:9092]
        check.crcs = true
        client.dns.lookup = default
        client.id =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        enable.auto.commit = false
        exclude.internal.topics = true
        fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
        fetch.min.bytes = 1
        group.id = spark-kafka-relation-9b6084ee-3efc-4ddc-ab81-5946d01576bb-driver-0
        heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
        interceptor.classes = []
        internal.leave.group.on.close = true
        isolation.level = read_uncommitted
        key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
        max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
        max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
        max.poll.records = 1
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        session.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

Please help me if anyone have solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that you are printing the Dataframe locally on each Spark executor. However your logs seem to be the one only for the driver which runs on a different machine.

When running this code in local mode you will not have any issues.

If you just want to print out the data in the console you can do:

```
val query = df 
.writeStream() 
.format("console") 
.outputMode("append") 
.option("checkpointLocation", "path/to/checkpoint/dir")
.start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. I tried that and also tried to print debug as mentioned in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51894431/spark-structured-streaming-can-not-recive-kafka-message but getting these error messages. `Group coordinator lookup failed: The coordinator is not available. Coordinator discovery failed, refreshing metadata`

Comment: How to resolve this error `Group coordinator lookup failed: The coordinator is not available.`